# Django: Multiple foreign key lookup

Tags: python, django, orm

I have a model `Table` with a `ManyToManyField` to model `Chair`.

I want a lookup to find the one table that has both `chair_1` and `chair_2` has its chairs

How do I do that lookup?

Answer (score 2):

Chain multiple `filter` calls:

```
sometable = Table.objects.filter(chair=chair_1).filter(chair=chair_2)
```

Comment: Okay, that would work, but is there a more elegant way?

Comment: I don't think so. You can't specify multiple values for `chair` in a single `filter` call because Python keyword arguments can't be repeated. You could test out what happens if you create two `Q` objects and `&` them together: `filter(Q(chair=chair_1) & Q(chair=chair_2))` but I'm not sure that works - or that it's any more elegant than the chained filters.